# Is there a Variable Base64 safe Encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, base64

Wondering if there already is a Variable Length Encoder/Decoder out there that is Base64 safe.

Similar to [UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) but that keeps to the 64 characters `[A-Za-z0-9/+]` allowed in Base64?

Basically something that uses either `+` or `/` for the start of a variable-length encoding block and keeps the rest as direct characters `[A-Za-z0-9]` + either `/` or `+` depending on which one is picked for signaling variable-length encoding block.

Comment: Not sure to follow you. A UTF7 decoder should be good for you, and as encoder, just implement UTF7 without treating specially the few extra symbols. I do not know any existing encoding, because you lose also spaces and new-line characters.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, yes I would expect the encoder to encode spaces and newline characters into a base64 safe representation (using the variable length encoding)